# How do I display "public gps traces" with Leaflet in my OSM map?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I can see the flag toggled in the querystring when I go openstreetmaps, but in my leaflet implementation of a map, I cannot get "Public GPS Traces" or"Cycle Map" to display. I am new to Leaflet, and assume its a layer. But there are many variants of layers and I'm not sure how to ask it to display these.

Here's my code...

```
var map = L.map( 'wwmap', {
  center: [41.2779, -72.7073],
  minZoom: 9,
  zoom: 13,   
}) 
  L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo( map )
```

In the following URL, I can see the layer flags being passed, (layers=CG). Not sure how to do get them to display in my embeded default map with leaflet.
Sample URL with querystring:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/41.2812/-72.7147&layers=CG

Answer (score 2):

These flags (layers=CG) are irrelevant for you. They just tell which tile sources to activate.

Take a look at the images your browser loads and you will see the URLs for these tile sources. The GPS layer is located at `http://gps-{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/lines/` and the cycle layer is at `http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/`.

For a list of possible tile servers take a look at:

- [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles)
- [Leaflet Provider Demo](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)
- [mapstyle.petschge.de](http://mapstyle.petschge.de/)
- [Map Compare](https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/)
- [switch2osm.org](https://switch2osm.org/providers/)

Note that each tile server has a specific [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) you have to follow. Moreover, some (e.g. the tiles from Thunderforest) require an API key.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add two tile layers, to achieve public gps traces

```
 var map = new L.Map("map", { center: [37.8, -96.9], zoom: 4})
                    .addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"))
                    .addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://gps-{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/lines/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"));
```